# Understanding the embedding of $W^{\infty, 2}$

Tags: derivatives, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, distribution-theory

I am trying to understand Sobolev's embedding theorem, more precisely to understand when a Sobolev generalized function of infinite order is smooth of some order.

Consider the following statement (from these [online notes - pdf file](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~canzani/docs/Laplacian.pdf), page 62):

> If $f \in H^k (\Omega) = W^{k, 2} (\Omega)$, then $f \in C^s (\overline \Omega)$ for all $s < k - \frac n 2$.

I don't get it. Does this mean that if $k = \infty$ and $s \in \Bbb N$, then every element of $H^\infty (\Omega)$ is smooth of order $s$, and thus it belongs to $C^\infty (\overline \Omega)$, so that all elements of $H^\infty$ are in fact smooth functions? Or is the theorem not valid for $k = \infty$?

Comment: Typically, the Sobolev space $H^k(\Omega)$ is only defined for $k \in \mathbb{N}$. But if $f \in H^k(\Omega)$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, then (by the above theorem), $f \in C^\infty(\bar\Omega)$.